# Tree navigation of nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-lists

i am trying to develop a navigation tree for my website, but had no luck with its dynamic arrangement.
The problem is:
i want to open the internal UL whenever there is clicked on Internal LI's , i am able to get index of the clicked internal Ul but cant use that index variable globally.

- the page is getting reloaded everytime i click on any link so is there a solution using cookies??

here is the html:

```
<ul id="menu">
          <li> <a href="#">Order Management</a>
              <ul id="test">
              <li><a href="#" class="even">orders</a></li>


      <li><a href="#" class="odd">Search Orders</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" class="even">Orderdetail</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


    <li> <a href="#">Discount Management</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="even">Subject</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="odd">Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="even">Publisher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="odd">Author</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="even">Particular Book</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li> <a href="#">Upload File</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="even">Upload excel file</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Reports</a>
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#" class="even">data over view</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" class="odd">Out Of Stock Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="even">Invoice Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="odd">SerachInvoicDispacthed</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href="#">Store Management</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="even">Currency</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="odd">Add Country</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


      </ul>
```

here is the Js:

```
    function initMenu() {
                   $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();

          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
        var myIndex = 0;
                   var items = $('#menu ul').click(function() {
                   //e.preventDefault();
                   myIndex = items.index(this);
                   console.log('the index is:'+myIndex);
//here i got index in var myIndex
                    }
                   );
//but i can not access myIndex here , it keeps returning zero
$('#menu  ul:eq('+myIndex+')').show("slow");

      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

my account is already blocked because of this question once , i request you people as i am very eager to get solution of this question. 
here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ekn2V/1/
there are no actual links but when i use real links the page get reload as defined in my struts.xml , so the page reloads everything that here occured by js is overlooked please tell me a cookie or something like that related solution.
i have experience in java se development and i am noob in web development.
any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You don't want to use existing UIs? For example: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html

Comment: yes exactly!!! but whenever i click on any of link my page got reload (main design layout that can't be modified) but is there a way by show()ing it using cookies.. sorry i forgot to mention previously.

Comment: I don't get you, please explain. Or better create http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see problem in action.

Comment: gotchA!!!!!  cookies i love you......

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want to reload/shift after clicking on `A` element, you need to disable the default browser behavior for the action. You can do it in the click event handler like:

```
$('#menu li a').click(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
 //..
});
```

Second, you do not need any JavaScript at all for tree navigation if you go with details/summary elements of HTML 5.1. Find here
https://codepen.io/dsheiko/details/MvEpXm/ a working example of customized tree build with details/summary, featuring also CSS3 transition to animate the marker on expand. This this blog post http://dsheiko.com/weblog/building-real-life-applications-with-functional-elements-of-html-5-2/ you can find other examples and explanation how to use it with polyfill to gain support in old IE